# Smallest integers a and b for which $n\leq \frac{a}{b}\leq m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I saw an example of this in my highschool textbook, but am wondering whether there is a general approach to this problem. (Where $m-n<1$)

An upper bound can easily be found by finding the first integer b such that $\frac{1}{b}< m-n$ (then just determining a), but then all I can do is check the integers less than b for smaller possible solutions (without checking factors of denominators already discarded). Is there a faster algorithm?

Comment: Are $m$ and $n$ real numbers? Rational numbers? Or...?